# Regular Expression for the specific String format

Tags: regex, url, string-formatting

I need to know the specific string regex for the following string:

```
market://details?id=com.package.id
```

so `market://details?id=` must be common for all inputs 
the next may vary like for example:

```
com.bundle.id or
org.package  or
com.bundle.id.myapp
```

etc anything with minimum of 2 dots (".")
the second string shall not have any special character

Comment: `org.package`minimum of 2 dots????????

Comment: Try: `(\w+(?:\.\w+){2,})`

Comment: yeah sorry single dot is also allowe. vks

Comment: \w+ match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_] kums :O
i just need 
market://details?id=

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
(?:market:\/\/details\?id=)(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)
```

[**Regex101 Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/yG7zB9)

Comment: (market:\/\/details\?=+(\.\w+){2,}) shouldnt this be working fine ?

Comment: I've added a demo link!

Comment: You mean JavaScript? Yes! Change the `flavor` option in RegEx101 and you can test it in JavaScript and use the code generator if you want JS code.

Comment: @SheikhOzairBilal this will match `market://details?id=welcome.dead.test.` as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
^market:\/\/details\?id=(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oP2xN3/1